# How to tell if tabs or spaces are being used in vim

Tags: vim

I have a file that has data such as:

```
1  Foo
2  Bar
3  Kazam
```

Is it possible using `vim` to know if a space is being used a delimited vs a tab?

Answer (score 7):

From [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19012475/5419599), there is a clever trick you can use:

> ```
> :syntax on
> :set syntax=whitespace
> ```
>
> These are syntax highlighting rules for the [Whitespace programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_%28programming_language%29) - tabs show in green and spaces in red. :)

Answer (score 3):

There are at least three:

1. `:set list` to set list mode as already indicated.
2. `:list` to print the current or a range of lines in list mode.
3. <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> to print the value of the character at the cursor.